# Python for loop execution

Tags: python, for-loop, python-2.7

```
for a in sorted(arr):
    doSomething()
```

vs

```
sArr = sorted(arr)
for a in sArr:
    doSomething()
```

are those 2 are the same exactly, or will one consume more cpu cycles then the other?

meaning, will sorted(arr) gets called every loop in the first example?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're pretty much the same.

[The documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#for) says:

> The expression list is evaluated once; it should yield an iterable object.

So, there's no risk of the `sorted()` call happening more than once, in the above code.

The first form is still better, since it's shorter and more concise, and might make it possible to optimize better (since the intepreter could figure out that the sorted list goes totally out of scope after the loop finishes).

Answer (score 4):

The are not the same exactly, but the difference is minimal. When in doubt, use the `dis` module to find out:

```
>>> import dis
>>> def f():
...     for a in sorted(arr):
...         doSomething()
... 
>>> def g():
...     sArr = sorted(arr)
...     for a in sArr:
...         doSomething()
... 
>>> dis.dis(f)
  2           0 SETUP_LOOP              27 (to 30)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (sorted)
              6 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (arr)
              9 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             12 GET_ITER            
        >>   13 FOR_ITER                13 (to 29)
             16 STORE_FAST               0 (a)

  3          19 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (doSomething)
             22 CALL_FUNCTION            0
             25 POP_TOP             
             26 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           13
        >>   29 POP_BLOCK           
        >>   30 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             33 RETURN_VALUE        
>>> dis.dis(g)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (sorted)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (arr)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              9 STORE_FAST               0 (sArr)

  3          12 SETUP_LOOP              21 (to 36)
             15 LOAD_FAST                0 (sArr)
             18 GET_ITER            
        >>   19 FOR_ITER                13 (to 35)
             22 STORE_FAST               1 (a)

  4          25 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (doSomething)
             28 CALL_FUNCTION            0
             31 POP_TOP             
             32 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           19
        >>   35 POP_BLOCK           
        >>   36 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             39 RETURN_VALUE
```

As you can see, the `g()` function adds a `STORE_FAST` and `LOAD_FAST` operation. You also use a little more memory, as the sorted results are kept around until the `sArr` variable is cleaned up, while in `f()` the sorted results can be cleaned up immediately following the conclusion of the loop.

The `CALL_FUNCTION` executes the `sorted()` function; it is only executed once.

Comment: +1: Goosh , beat me in 29 sec. Even the wording "when in doubt"

Comment: Thus changed my answer, to beat your telepathy

Answer (score 1):

`sorted()` returns an object which is subsequently iterated over. It is only called once.

Answer (score 0):

Its the same as others have said. Remember when in doubt (though trivial and obvious in this case) always run the disassemble over the source. Alternatively, you can run it through cProfile, even when the disassemble be different, cProfile would give a fair idea about the performance

```
>>> def foo():
    total = 0
    arr = range(10000000,1,-1)
    for a in sorted(arr):
        total += a


>>> def bar():
    total = 0
    for a in sorted(range(10000000,1,-1)):
        total += a


>>> cProfile.run("bar()")
         5 function calls in 2.614 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    1.914    1.914    2.614    2.614 <pyshell#88>:1(bar)
        1    0.000    0.000    2.614    2.614 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
        1    0.266    0.266    0.266    0.266 {range}
        1    0.434    0.434    0.434    0.434 {sorted}


>>> cProfile.run("foo()")
         5 function calls in 2.477 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    1.779    1.779    2.346    2.346 <pyshell#86>:1(foo)
        1    0.130    0.130    2.477    2.477 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
        1    0.152    0.152    0.152    0.152 {range}
        1    0.415    0.415    0.415    0.415 {sorted}


>>>
```

As you would observe here

1. Sorted is called only once in both cases
2. There are 5 function calls in each cases
3. They have almost the same performance.

Comment: For something this small, I'd use `timeit` instead to eliminate variations in OS scheduling.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: My main intention in using `cProfile` is to show the `functions calls` and the `ncalls`

Comment: Ah, okay. You want to demonstrate the call structure, not the performance difference.